# How to create POI's (AR View - Location Based) on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, location, augmented-reality

How to create POI's (AR View - Location Based) on Android

//Now. I use a Meatio SDK . When i start Metaio tutorial project (Location Based) on Android (Genymotion) it's a black screen My gps and camera is turn on genymotion setting camera is webcam().

http://upic.me/show/55199646

// request a example code for android other API

Comment: any info in logs ? I had similar problem with Google Maps API in my app - the reason was problem with libraries, i've found info about that in logs

Answer (score 0):

if you say which version of SDK you are using to develop maybe it could be possible to help you, as i experienced there is some version those are not compatible with some android versions or cell phones.